# Checkbox está checked

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, if

Necesito saber si los checkbox están checked para almacenar o no los datos.

Tengo el siguiente checkbox:

```
<mat-radio-button color="primary" *ngIf="type === 'category'" class="example-margin" value="{{d.value}}" (change)="onChange($event)">{{d.text}}</mat-radio-button>
```

Y tengo esto en el typescript:

```
onChange(event) {
let data = {};

if (this.type === 'category') {
  data[this.type + 'Id'] = event.value;
  this.noticeService.addToStepsData(this.stepsData, data, this.type);
}
else if (this.type === 'brand') {
  data[this.type + 'Id'] = event.source.value;
  this.array.push(data);
  this.noticeService.addToStepsData(this.stepsData, this.array, this.type);
}}
```

En el `else if` antes de hacer el `push` necesito pasarle la validación con `if` para saber si esta checked o no.

Comment: Angular tiene reactiveForms y el NgModel. ¿Estás usando alguno de esos?

Comment: Hize un ejemplo con reactiveForms, te va facilitar mucho la vida. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7rmqms

Answer (score 0):

Debe comprobar event.target.checked para poder ver si esta seleccionado, así es como se puede lograr:

```
<input id="is3dCheckBox" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

Y en tu código:

```
var element = <HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("is3dCheckBox");
var isChecked = element.checked;
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda pero no se en que parte del typescript poner la validación.

Comment: Agregala dentro de tu método. Debería de funcionar.

Comment: he añadido eso dentro de mi metodo y he hecho un if (!isChecked) que haga lo que tenga que hacer, pero me sale en la consola: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Comment: y trabajo con typescript no se si tiene que ver pero la variable element recibe null.

Comment: Creo que no podré ayudar hermano.

Comment: Nada, gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Si men, lo siento tiene rato que no trabajo con eso.

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion de `mat-radio-button`, existe una propiedad llamada [`checked`](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api) que actualiza el modelo en base a si esta seleccionado no.

Por lo que solo tendras que asignarle un modelo de tu componente:

```
<mat-radio-button 
value="{{d.value}}"
[checked]="checkSeleccionado" <----- asignadole modelo a la propiedad [checked]
(change)="onChange($event)">
  {{d.text}}
</mat-radio-button>
```

Entonces solo tendrias que preguntar si esta seleccionado:

```
export class NombreComponente {
    onChange(event) {
        //...
       if(checkSeleccionado){

      }
   //...
}
```